# Why is my output freezing when it gets to this section of the code?

Tags: c++, object, vector, infinite-loop

I'm trying to compare two decks of cards, yet every time I try another method of doing it, I get the same result... Everything before the code outputs, and it just freezes as soon as it hits the comparison code, as if it's stuck in an infinite loop.

I've tried for loops, static variables, do-while loops, etc. This is my first time leaving the loop at the client code.

The code that supposedly throws the program into an infinite loop.

```
    while (repeatLoop == false)
    {
        deck1.shuffleDeck();
        counter++;
        repeatLoop = deck1.compareDecks();
    }
```

compareDecks function.

```
bool deck::compareDecks()
{
    int deckCount = 0;

    suitType tempOriginalSuit;
    suitType tempShuffleSuit;

    rankType tempOriginalRank;
    rankType tempShuffleRank;

    while (index < 52)
    {
        tempOriginalSuit = originalCardDeck[index].getSuit();
        tempShuffleSuit = shuffledCardDeck[index].getSuit();

        if (int(tempOriginalSuit) == int(tempShuffleSuit))
        {
            tempOriginalRank = originalCardDeck[index].getRank();
            tempShuffleRank = shuffledCardDeck[index].getRank();

            if (int(tempOriginalRank) == int(tempShuffleRank))
            {
                deckCount++;

                if (deckCount == 52)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

The shuffleDeck function
(This function pushes back the first card from the first half of the deck and the first card from the second half of the deck towards the end until all 52 cards have been pushed in this pattern. This makes the deck have 52 x 2 cards (with the second half of the deck being the perfect shuffle), so I delete the first half of the cards using .erase as it is not needed)

```
void deck::shuffleDeck()
{
    for (int a = 0, b = 2; a < 2 && b < 4; a++, b++)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < 15; i++)
        {
            shuffledCardDeck.push_back(card{ static_cast<cardSpace::suitType>(a),
                                             static_cast<cardSpace::rankType>(i) });

            shuffledCardDeck.push_back(card{ static_cast<cardSpace::suitType>(b),
                                             static_cast<cardSpace::rankType>(i) });
        }
    }

    shuffledCardDeck.erase(shuffledCardDeck.begin(), 
                           shuffledCardDeck.begin() + (shuffledCardDeck.size() / 2));
}
```

The two decks initialized by this constructor.

```
deck::deck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++)
        {
            originalCardDeck.push_back(card{ static_cast<cardSpace::suitType>(i),
                                            static_cast<cardSpace::rankType>(j) });
            shuffledCardDeck.push_back(card{ static_cast<cardSpace::suitType>(i),
                                            static_cast<cardSpace::rankType>(j) });
        }
    }

}
```

Also note that I've done a perfect shuffle on the shuffledCardDeck vector in another function. I'm trying to repeat the perfectShuffle function until it reaches it's original state and output how many times it took to do this.

I get an infinite loop.

EDIT: I've decided to add the return false; statement in the compareDecks function into the if-else. Also, I think what's causing the problem is that my index i is reset to zero everytime it is called again. Are there any solutions you guys could propose to this? I've tried using static variables, but they just would not increment in the for loop.

EDIT 2: I enclosed my if statements within the curly braces, per users' request, as it's a flaw in my code.

EDIT 3: After commenting out

```
deck1.shuffleDeck()
```

The compareDecks function returned true, stating that the decks are equal, which isn't supposed to happen... This caused the loop to end after only one loop.

Comment: `repeatLoop = deck1.compareDecks();`

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've made the edit, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Be careful when not using accolades properly. You are missing some for the if statements. This can cause some unwanted behaviour. When not using {} only the next is part of the if. The rest below is no longer part of it and will always be executed. Always, always use { and }

Comment: @AngoMango `for (int a = 0, b = 2; a < 2, b < 4; a++, b++)` -- Exactly what is your intention here, especially this: `a < 2, b < 4`?

Comment: Careful:  I'm worried that `if (deckCount == 52)` is indented as far as it is.  It it *not* part of the `if (int(tempOriginalRank) == int(tempShuffleRank))` condition block - there are no braces `{ }` surrounding it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The first line is to basically split the deck into half. I would be able to push the first card of my first half to the end, and then push the first card of my second half to the end. If I do this fully, I would have done a perfect shuffle. As for the second line, I wanted to make sure the first half of the deck didn't overstep into the boundaries of the second half. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Wyck That's very true. My code is full of errors, but I feel like there is an underlying problem that I'm missing besides these syntax errors since I've since fixed it and I still get the same error. I'll make the edit.

Comment: If you comment out the `shuffleDeck` usages, does the `compareDecks` return true?

Comment: @AngoMango No, what I am saying is what that syntax is supposed to denote.  You seemed to have assumed the comma means what you think it means.  If you mean both conditions are to be true for the loop to continue, then we have `&&` for that purpose.

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code where it is looping infinitely (or at least for a very long time), and figure out what is getting wedged.  Using a debugger is an invaluable programming skill.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was under the impression that the comma allows for multiple condition statements under one for loop.

Comment: @ChrisO It does come out as true which makes no sense since it shouldn't be equal.

Comment: @AngoMango For laughs, just change that to `&&`.  The middle part of the loop is the condition to make the loop continue.  I think you've been bitten by the comma operator.  The middle part of the loop must be an expression that evaluates to `true` or `false`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, I don't get an infinite error loop anymore, but the shuffleDeck function doesn't even shuffle the deck for me, along with the fact that the compareDecks function still returns true

Comment: `while (repeatLoop == false)` feels **really** wrong. Shouldn't it be `while (repeatLoop == true)`?

Comment: In addition, your `compareDecks` function seems to be just this: `bool deck::compareDecks() {
    return std::equal(originalCardDeck.begin(), originalCardDeck.begin() + 52, 
                      shuffledCardDeck.begin(), shuffledCardDeck.begin() + 52,
                      [](card& c1, card& c2) { return c1.getSuit() == c2.getSuit() && 
                                                       c1.getRank() == c2.getRank(); });
}`

Comment: I was expecting your `shuffleDeck` routine to be based on the current state of the deck.  It is not.  It synthesizes new cards (52 of them) in a very specific configuration, then deletes the original deck.  `shuffleDeck`will always return the same configuration.  So calling shuffleDeck again, will not accomplish anything.  This is because you push a new card that is based on the loop index, (e.g.: rank i) rather than its position in the deck (`originalCardDeck[i]`)

Comment: @TedLyngmo You’re right, That’s bad style, I’ll fix it.

Comment: In addition, I really don't see any shuffling going on, or at least what I would expect to see in a shuffle function.  I see no call to `std::shuffle` or any function remotely related to shuffling.  Just a loop pushing on cards.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The criteria was to pull off a perfect shuffle, meaning that it shouldn't be random. It was the best function I could come up with.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Re `repeatLoop == true`.  Superficially, yes, of course.  To state the reverse is a _what-the-heck_?  But logically, it's right, because I believe the intent is trying to count how many perfect shuffles it takes to restore the deck to its original order.  And the `repeatLoop` variable was set to the compare function result, which we want to continue shuffling while the decks are different, which means, keep shuffling while the compare is false (returns false when different).  `repeatLoop` is the opposite name of the intent of the variable - and that's bad for sure!

Comment: This all would have been much easier to understand if you had mentioned at the top of your original question that you were *trying to count how many perfect shuffles it takes to restore a deck to its original order*.

Comment: @Wyck Yes, I also read the last comment in the question and understood that the logic was reversed with regards to the variable name. Maintenance hell :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was expecting you to actually shuffle the deck.

Your code was pushing a specific, newly synthesized card onto the end of the deck:

```
           shuffledCardDeck.push_back(card{ static_cast<cardSpace::suitType>(a),
                                            static_cast<cardSpace::rankType>(i) });
```

For example, the first card it will push is always the 2 of 0's (Whatever the 0th suit is).  That's not what you want.  You actually want to push a copy of the card that is at a specific position `index` in the deck.  For example, loop `index` from `0` to `25` and then push `shuffledCardDeck[index]` and `shuffledCardDeck[26 + index]`.

Then you can still wrap up by using your technique of erasing the first half of the deck.

```cpp
void deck::shuffleDeck()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 26; ++index) {
        shuffledCardDeck.push_back(shuffledCardDeck[index]);
        shuffledCardDeck.push_back(shuffledCardDeck[26 + index]);
    }

    shuffledCardDeck.erase(shuffledCardDeck.begin(), 
                           shuffledCardDeck.begin() + 52);
}
```

Comment: Would your method work if my shuffledCardDeck was a vector made up of objects? That's how I got this: card{ static_cast<cardSpace::suitType>(a),
                                            static_cast<cardSpace::rankType>(i) }. Where I'm pushing a card object with specific elements to the end of the vector.

Comment: @AngoMango, yes.  Beware if your vector is a vector of pointers to objects vs a vector of the objects themselves, but (normal C++ issues aside) yes, it will copy a card structure at position `index` and append that copy to the end of the vector `shuffledCardDeck.push_back(shuffledCardDeck[index])`.  If you share your declaration of the vector, I could answer with greater certainty.

Comment: I'll test the code out, but the declaration of my vectors are in the default constructor of the deck class for both vectors. I declared the two vectors in the private member section as: vector<card>originalCardDeck; & vector<card>shuffledCardDeck;

Comment: @AngoMango Yes, that's a vector of `card` objects.  That will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifying the value in the loop, you're using a double equals sign:

`repeatLoop == deck1.compareDecks();`

That would explain your observed behavior.

Comment: I made the change, but I'm still getting the infinite loop. However, I'll edit the question to include the changes.